# Proximal Operator of $ f \left( U \right) = -\log \det \left( U \right) $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

This is an assignment problem which I failed to solve in a couple of days.

Denote the set of all $n \times n$ symmetric matrices and the set of all $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrices by $\mathbb{S}^n$ and $\mathbb{S}^n_{++}$ respectively. Let $f: \mathbb{S}^n_{++} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$f(U) = -\log \det (U) \text{ for } U \in \mathbb{S}^n_{++}$$
We are asked to find the proximal mapping $\text{prox}_f$ of $f$.

**My question is:**

1. **What is the domain of $\text{prox}_f$?** It is not mentioned in the problem. I suppose it is $\mathbb{S}^n$ and I will explain it later.
2. The function $g(U;X) = -\log \det(U) + \frac{1}{2}\|U - X\|_F^2$ is differentiable in each entry $U_{ij}$ of $U$. If I did not make mistakes in the calculation, the minimization problem 
   $$ \text{prox}_f(X) = \text{argmin}_{U \in \mathbb{S}^n_{++}} g(U;X) $$
   can be formulated as
   $$ 0 = \frac{\partial g(U;X)}{\partial U_{ij}} = -U^{-1}_{ji} + U_{ij} - X_{ij} = -U^{-1}_{ij} + U_{ij} - X_{ij}$$
   and therefore $U = \text{prox}_f(X) \in \mathbb{S}^n_{++}$ should satisfy
   $$U - U^{-1} = X$$
   This also sees why $X$ has to be symmetric. But I cannot proceed from here: **How do we calculate $U$ from $X$ in practice?**

Thanks in advance. Any comments or hints are welcome.

Comment: Look at the scalar case first; i.e., $n=1$.

Comment: For the scalar case, domain of $\text{prox}_f$ is simply $\mathbb{R}$ and the quadratic equation $u^2 - xu - 1 = 0$ has two real roots since $\Delta = (-x)^2 - 4(1)(-1) = x^2 + 4 > 0$ and the roots are of opposite sign since $\frac{c}{a} = \frac{-1}{1} = -1$. So the image of $x$ under $\text{prox}_f$ can be taken as the positive root. But I failed to generalize to $n > 1$.

Comment: Now consider trying to prove that this quadratic equation should be applied to *each eigenvalue* of $X$. (After all, consider the case where $X$ is diagonal: won't this require $U$ to be diagonal as well? Then consider the case where $X$ is *similar* to a diagonal---which is always true!) This should give you an easy way to derive the result. I'll bet you will then be able to simplify the computations so that a full eigenvalue decomposition of $X$ is not required (perhaps just a Cholesky).

Comment: Sorry I still do not fully understand. If $X$ is diagonal, then $U$ is a diagonal matrix with positive entries. Then it is done. But for $X \in \mathbb{S}^n$, we have to solve the equation $U - U^{-1} = QDQ^T$. I think you mean we can rewrite it into $W - W^{-1} = D$ but I cannot see a substitution to do so.

Comment: The point is, if $QXQ^T$ is diagonal, then so must $QUQ^T$ be.

Comment: Thanks! I think I see it now, finally!

Comment: Great! Now answer your own question and collect some points :-)

Comment: Thanks for your great help! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the hints from @Michael Grant, we let $X = QDQ^T$ is the eigenvalue decomposition of $X$ with $Q$ being the orthogonal matrix consisting of eigenvectors of $X$. Let $w^*_i$ be the positive root of
$$w_i^2 - D_{ii}w_i - 1 = 0$$
The existence and uniqueness of the positive root is an analogue of the case $n = 1$.
Let $W^* = \text{diag}(w^*_1, w^*_2, \ldots, w^*_n)$ and it satisfies
$$W^* - (W^*)^{-1} = D$$
Letting $U^* = QW^*Q^T$ yields
$$U^* - (U^*)^{-1} = X$$
and it is straightforward to check $U^* \in \mathbb{S}^n_{++}$.